# While generating output.html using md file and template file using apiblueprint, the generated file is empty

Tags: go, apiblueprint

I went through following steps:

1. Install go and add $GOPATH env variable to a new empty directory.
2. Install snowcrash. Parses markdown file according to apiblueprint
   spec.
3. Install mercurial. On a Mac using homebrew use: brew install hg
4. Install these Go modules:
5. `go get bitbucket.org/pkg/inflect`
6. `go get github.com/hashicorp/go-version`
7. `go get github.com/russross/blackfriday`
8. symlink this repo's generator directory to $GOPATH/src/generator
9. Run the html generator:

   a. `cd $GOPATH/src/generator/main`

   b. `go run main.go -spec ~/projects/repo/filename.md -template ~/projects/repo/filename.tmpl -out test.html`

Comment: not sure about your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you take a look at [aglio](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio), an API Blueprint renderer which can render your API Blueprint as HTML.

```
$ npm install -g aglio
$ aglio -i input.apib -o output.html
```

This should do everything you need.